# Windowed Partition Functions Assistance Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that contains all the pay records for the current year.  I'd like to add a year-to-date and a month-to-date and hopefully not have to sum them separately and then join the results.  Here is my data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Test](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [CheckDate] [date] NULL,
    [Units] [decimal](19, 5) NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](19, 5) NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](19, 5) NULL,
    [TaxAmount] [decimal](19, 5) NULL,
    [DeductAmount] [decimal](19, 5) NULL,
    [BenefitAmount] [decimal](19, 5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (1, N'1', CAST(N'2015-01-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (2, N'2', CAST(N'2015-01-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (3, N'1', CAST(N'2015-02-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (4, N'2', CAST(N'2015-02-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (5, N'1', CAST(N'2015-03-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (6, N'2', CAST(N'2015-03-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (7, N'1', CAST(N'2015-04-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (8, N'2', CAST(N'2015-04-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (9, N'1', CAST(N'2015-05-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (10, N'2', CAST(N'2015-05-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (11, N'1', CAST(N'2015-06-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (12, N'2', CAST(N'2015-06-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (13, N'1', CAST(N'2015-07-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (14, N'2', CAST(N'2015-07-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (15, N'1', CAST(N'2015-08-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (16, N'2', CAST(N'2015-08-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (17, N'1', CAST(N'2015-09-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (18, N'2', CAST(N'2015-09-01' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (19, N'1', CAST(N'2015-01-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (20, N'2', CAST(N'2015-01-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (21, N'1', CAST(N'2015-02-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (22, N'2', CAST(N'2015-02-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (23, N'1', CAST(N'2015-03-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (24, N'2', CAST(N'2015-03-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (25, N'1', CAST(N'2015-04-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (26, N'2', CAST(N'2015-04-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (27, N'1', CAST(N'2015-05-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (28, N'2', CAST(N'2015-05-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (29, N'1', CAST(N'2015-06-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (30, N'2', CAST(N'2015-06-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (31, N'1', CAST(N'2015-07-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (32, N'1', CAST(N'2015-08-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(10.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(400.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(100.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(50.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[_Test] ([Id], [EmployeeID], [CheckDate], [Units], [Rate], [Amount], [TaxAmount], [DeductAmount], [BenefitAmount]) VALUES (33, N'2', CAST(N'2015-08-15' AS Date), CAST(40.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(12.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(480.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(120.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)), CAST(60.00000 AS Decimal(19, 5)))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[_Test] OFF
GO
```

I want to return a paycheck's data along with the month to date and year to date values included given a single date.  I'm thinking something like this might work, but i'm having trouble setting up my window.

```
select employeeid, CheckDate, Units
        sum(Units) over (Partition by employeeid, CheckDate 
                            ORDER BY CheckDate 
                            ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [MTD Units],

        sum(Units) over (Partition by EmployeeId, CheckDate
                            ORDER BY CheckDate 
                            ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [YTD Units],
        , Rate, Amount,

        sum(Amount) over (Partition by employeeid, CheckDate 
                            ORDER BY CheckDate 
                            ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [MTD Amount],

        sum(Amount) over (Partition by EmployeeId, CheckDate
                            ORDER BY CheckDate 
                            ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [YTD Amount],

from _Test
where CheckDate = '6/15/15'
```

The reason I was thinking using the Over would work, because if i take off my WHERE clause and do the following, I do get a sum of all the items on every line.

```
select employeeid, CheckDate, Units
        , Rate, Amount
        ,sum(Amount) over (Partition by EmployeeId) [All]
from _Test

empidCheckDate  Units   Rate    Amount  All
1   2015-01-01  40.00   10.00   400.00  6800.00
1   2015-02-01  40.00   10.00   400.00  6800.00
1   2015-03-01  40.00   10.00   400.00  6800.00
2   2015-01-15  40.00   12.00   480.00  7680.00
2   2015-02-15  40.00   12.00   480.00  7680.00
2   2015-03-15  40.00   12.00   480.00  7680.00
```

I was thinking I could restrict it with a window.

My desired output is as such:

```
Id  EmpID   CheckDate   Units   MTD Units   YTD Units   Rate    Amount  MTD Amount  YTD Amount  TaxAmount   DeductAmount    BenefitAmount
29    1     2015-06-15  40.00   80.00       520.00      10.00   400.00  800.00      5200.00     100.00      50.00           50.00
30    2     2015-06-15  40.00   80.00       520.00      12.00   480.00  960.00      6240.00     120.00      60.00           60.00
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Can you reformat your title as a question?

Answer (score 0):

Should just need to adjust your `PARTITION BY` to break it apart by `YEAR` and/or `MONTH`:

```
select employeeid, CheckDate, Units,
    sum(Units) over (Partition by employeeid, YEAR(CheckDate),MONTH(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [MTD Units],

    sum(Units) over (Partition by EmployeeId, YEAR(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [YTD Units],
    , Rate, Amount,

    sum(Amount) over (Partition by employeeid, YEAR(CheckDate),MONTH(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [MTD Amount],

    sum(Amount) over (Partition by EmployeeId, YEAR(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [YTD Amount],

from _Test
```

This way, the running total amount you've created will be constrained to the proper time period, you don't want an amount from last month added to this month's running total.  If you only want values for a specific date, you'll need to use a subquery/cte to filter after you calculate the YTD and MTD, because the necessary amounts won't be available for aggregation if you put the filter in the same query:

```
;with cte AS (select employeeid, CheckDate, Units,
    sum(Units) over (Partition by employeeid, YEAR(CheckDate),MONTH(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [MTD Units],

    sum(Units) over (Partition by EmployeeId, YEAR(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [YTD Units],
    , Rate, Amount,

    sum(Amount) over (Partition by employeeid, YEAR(CheckDate),MONTH(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [MTD Amount],

    sum(Amount) over (Partition by EmployeeId, YEAR(CheckDate)
                        ORDER BY CheckDate 
                        ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) [YTD Amount],

    from _Test
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE CheckDate = '6/15/15'
```

Edit: Only adjusted `Amount` calculations initially, added `Units`

Comment: Can't I create a window of first quarter, for example, that encompasses "between '1/1/15' and '3/31/15' " ?  If so, then I wouldn't need a subquery for MTD, YTD ?  I guess my attempted approach was, give me all the records(ie YTD) and window the start/end date for current and window MTD as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question exactly, but you can get quarter instead with `DATEPART(quarter,CheckDate)`.  You only need a subquery if you want to display anything less than the whole range of days included in a calculation window. Does that clear things up?